# How do I mix constants and adhoc return values efficiently?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get back into C++ but it's changed a bit in 20 years

I am processing a network stream that has a bunch of strings.

I know what the vast majority of these strings could be, but not all of them

If I knew what all the strings could be, I would map these strings to an enum so that comparisons are cheap and I would not have millions of repeated strings in memory

As I know what most of the strings could be, I thought i would create a file with a bunch of const std::strings and dynamically create the strings I don't know about. However, I seem to be copying the const std::string rather than linking directly to them

I wrote a silly program to demonstrate.

I used cities below. I know about Seattle and Tacoma, but not about the random cities.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

const std::string SEATTLE("Seattle");

const std::string TACOMA("Tacoma");

std::random_device rd;

std::mt19937 gen(rd());

std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 'Z' - 'A');

auto next = []() -> char {

    return static_cast<char>('A' + dist(gen));
};

const std::string factory(int in) {

    switch (in) {
        case 0: {
            return SEATTLE;
        }
        case 1: {
            return TACOMA;
        }
        default: {

            std::string retval(5, 0);

            std::generate_n(retval.begin(), 5, next);

            return retval;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    std::cout << "SEATTLE=" << &SEATTLE << std::endl;

    std::cout << "TACOMA=" << &TACOMA << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {

            const std::string value = factory(i);

            std::cout << "i=" << i << " " << value << " " << &value << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is my global Seattle and Tacoma to be returned, not a copy

How do I avoid copying constant strings yet maintain the same interface for strings I don't know about?

Or should I not care?

Thanks

Comment: std::string is like an integer. "What I want is my global 5 and 42 to be returned, not a copy". Makes sense? So does your original sentence.

Comment: "Or should I not care?" I wouldn't worry. You are probably thinking too soon to speed. Test it, first.

Comment: What you probably want to avoid is copying string *data*, i.e. the collection of characters each string is holding. This is however rather problematic. You need to consider the lifetime and ownership of your string data. Global constants obviously have no owner and their lifetime is that of the entire program. Factory-made strings are automatic. You cannot mix the two kinds together. Global ones are never destroyed, local ones are always destroyed at the end of the block. It follows you must make a local copy of a global string to be destroyed uniformly with other local strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse the known values without making copies and use objects constructed for unknown values by changing the strategy a little bit.

Pass a `std::function` to `factory` and call the function from `factory`.

```
void factory(int in, std::function<void(std::string const&)> f) {

   switch (in) {
      case 0:
         // SEATTLE is passed by reference. No need for copy.
         f(SEATTLE);

      case 1:
         // TACOMA is passed by reference. No need for copy.
         f(TACOMA);

      default:
         // Construct a new object for unknown values. 
         std::string retval(5, 0);
         std::generate_n(retval.begin(), 5, next);
         f(retval);
   }
}
```

and use it in `main` as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {

   for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {

      factory(i,
              [=](std::string const& value) { std::cout << "i=" << i << " " << value << " " << &value << std::endl;});
   }
}
```

Comment: I think that's right, or at least as good as it's going to get. Using an std::shared_ptr seems silly for the globals, but I'm disappointed there is no magic string cache. Thanks